# Display 2 Array values in foreach() loop - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-08-21
    [1] => 2012-08-22
    [2] => 2012-08-23
    [3] => 2012-08-24
    [4] => 2012-08-25
    [5] => 2012-08-26
    [6] => 2012-08-27
    [7] => 2012-08-28
    [8] => 2012-08-29
    [9] => 2012-08-30
)
```

To create this array I'm using this:

```
function getAllDatesBetweenTwoDates($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
{
    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}

$fromDate = '2012-08-21';
$toDate = '2012-08-30';

$dateArray = getAllDatesBetweenTwoDates($fromDate, $toDate);


for($i=0, $count = count($dateArray);$i<$count;$i++) {
 echo $dateArray[$i] . " - " . $dateArray[$i++] . "<br>";
}
```

But this skips the second date and just shows the same date next to each other, but I'm eventually wanting to put these arrays in a query to get data between each of the two dates.

This currently returns:

```
2012-08-21 - 2012-08-21
2012-08-23 - 2012-08-23
2012-08-25 - 2012-08-25
2012-08-27 - 2012-08-27
2012-08-29 - 2012-08-29
```

But I want it to return:

```
2012-08-21 - 2012-08-22
2012-08-22 - 2012-08-23
2012-08-23 - 2012-08-24
2012-08-24 - 2012-08-25
2012-08-25 - 2012-08-26
2012-08-26 - 2012-08-27
2012-08-27 - 2012-08-28
2012-08-28 - 2012-08-29
2012-08-29 - 2012-08-30
2012-08-30 - 2012-08-30
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increment `i` twice, and this is the problem. You have to use `$i+1` instead of `i++` inside `for` iteration:

```
for($i=0, $count = count($dateArray);$i<$count;$i++) {
 echo $dateArray[$i] . " - " . $dateArray[$i+1] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the function itself, it's in the way you print it (double increment). Try this loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($dateArray)-1;$i++) {
   echo $dateArray[$i] . " - " . $dateArray[$i+1] . "<br>";
}
```